# how make specific number of button can be selected and after select change the colors of those that selected

Tags: javascript, css

```css
ul.number-list li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.number-list li a {
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="number-list">
  <li>
    <a role="button">1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">11</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">31</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">12</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">16</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">6</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">12</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">21</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">44</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm new in javascript and I need help and I would be grateful if sombody help !
in this case I have a list of buttons and I want restrict the number of selecting buttons like 6 buttons.and each button can be select just for once and after select color of it get change.help me please to write this code.thank you

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to select at maximum a certain number of buttons, and change the colour of the selected ones?

Comment: yessss and button that is selected cant be deselect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var SelectCount=0;
function ButtonSelected(id) {
    if (SelectCount < 3) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor="red";
        SelectCount+=1;
    }
}
```

```css
ul.number-list li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.number-list li a {
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="number-list">
  <li >
    <a id="n1" onclick="ButtonSelected('n1')" role="button">1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n2" onclick="ButtonSelected('n2')" role="button">11</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n3" onclick="ButtonSelected('n3')" role="button">31</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n4" onclick="ButtonSelected('n4')" role="button">12</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n5" onclick="ButtonSelected('n5')" role="button">16</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n6" onclick="ButtonSelected('n6')" role="button">6</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n7" onclick="ButtonSelected('n7')" role="button">12</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n8" onclick="ButtonSelected('n8')" role="button">21</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n9" onclick="ButtonSelected('n9')" role="button">2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n10" onclick="ButtonSelected('n10')" role="button">44</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This code will change the button to red and increment the counter.  In this code, three buttons max can be selected. Buttons cannot be deselected.

Comment: thank you so much !how can make each button is selected could not be deselect ?

Comment: I'll update the code so a button once selected, cannot be deselected.

Comment: thanks.it works ! but still i have a little problem !hope you help again!

Comment: when user click on selected button twice it doesnt  considerd and doesnt decrease the number of selection

Comment: Correct.  In your prior comment you prohibited deselecting a button.  I updated the code to allow for your criteria.

Comment: I added a second answer.  The first is three max (no deselect).  The second is three max (deselection allowed + feedback).

Comment: Cool.  Accept the answer that resolved your question please.

Comment: hi .could you help me again!please

Answer (score 0):

```js
var SelectCount = 0;

function ButtonSelected(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor == "red") {
    SelectCount -= 1;
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "purple";
    document.getElementById("checker").innerHTML = SelectCount + " selected (3 max)";
  } else {
    if (SelectCount < 3) {
      document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
      SelectCount += 1;
      document.getElementById("checker").innerHTML = SelectCount + " selected (3 max)";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("checker").innerHTML = "You must unselect another button before selecting this one.<br />Maximum of three buttons selected reached.";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
ul.number-list li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.number-list li a {
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="number-list">
  <li>
    <a id="n1" onclick="ButtonSelected('n1')" role="button">1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n2" onclick="ButtonSelected('n2')" role="button">11</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n3" onclick="ButtonSelected('n3')" role="button">31</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n4" onclick="ButtonSelected('n4')" role="button">12</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n5" onclick="ButtonSelected('n5')" role="button">16</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n6" onclick="ButtonSelected('n6')" role="button">6</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n7" onclick="ButtonSelected('n7')" role="button">12</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n8" onclick="ButtonSelected('n8')" role="button">21</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n9" onclick="ButtonSelected('n9')" role="button">2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="n10" onclick="ButtonSelected('n10')" role="button">44</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="checker">
  Select up to three buttons.
</div>
```

This answer allows deselecting a button and provides user feedback as well.  As in my other answer, a max of three buttons can be selected at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.number-list li {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
}
ul.number-list li a {
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.number-list li a.selected {
  background: red;
}
<ul class="number-list">
  <li>
    <a role="button">1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">11</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">31</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">12</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">16</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">6</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">12</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">21</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a role="button">44</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {

    document.querySelectorAll("ul.number-list li a").addEventListener('click', function() {

      this.className = 'selected';
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you check and confirm?